# Set the value as a range of numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

My question is whether I can use a range as the value in a key:value pair in a hash. I am working on a problem where I am trying to return a letter grade (A-F) for an average of numerical grades (array of numbers). I have a working solution, but I came across something intriguing. Here is my code:

```
def get_grade(array)

  avg = (array.inject {|num, x| num + x}) / array.length

  grades = {
  "A" => [90..10]
  "B" => [80..89],
  "C" => [70..79],
  "D" => [60..69],
  "F" => [0..59],
  }
  grades.default = "Error"

  puts grades.key(avg)
  end

arraya = [100,90,100,99,99]
puts get_grade(arraya)
```

I know I could return the letter grade with either a case or an if statement. It seems like I should be able to use a hash instead but it doesn't work. Why can't I set up a hash with a range as value? Thanks.

Comment: You are missing a comma (and possibly the `0` of `100`) in your line for "A". You should also add your expected results in more detail, when I fix that error, I get no useful output . . . I could make it generate output perhaps, but no idea what you intend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to rewrite your method as the following:

```
def get_grade(array)

  avg = array.inject(:+) / array.length

  grades = {
  "A" => (90..100),
  "B" => (80..89),
  "C" => (70..79),
  "D" => (60..69),
  "F" => (0..59),
  }     

  grade = grades.find{|key, range| range.include?(avg) }

  grade.nil? ? "Unknown" : grade.first

end

arraya = [100,90,100,99,99]

puts get_grade(arraya) # => A
```

Comment: Nice, especially considering your age.  A variant would be `min_to_ltr = {90=>'A', 80=>'B', 70=>'C', 60=>'D', 0=>'F'}`, then `min_to_ltr[min_to_ltr.keys.find { |v| v <= avg }]`

Comment: This is exactly what I was I trying to do. Thanks! Can you walk me through the last line? I don't understand that one completely.

Comment: Beagle, [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) enumerates each element of the hash `grades` until it finds one that computes to `true` in the block, in which case it returns that element.  If the block computes to `false` or `nil` for all elements of `grades`, `find` returns `nil`.  Each element of the hash consists of a key and a value, which are represted by the block's local variables, `key` and `range`.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @beaglebets The avarage score can fall out of 0..100 range. For example, if you pass [100, 110] to the method, the avarage score will be 105. In that case the method will return 'Unknown'

Comment: why 'grade.first'? That is the part that I don't fully get. Does 'grades.find{|key, range| range.include?(avg) } return an array? I thought it would only return a key.

Comment: You're right. `grades.find` return an array, the first element is the key, the second is the value.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a case statement:

```
def get_grade(scores)
  case scores.inject(&:+) / scores.length
  when 90..100; 'A'
  when 80..89; 'B'
  when 70..79; 'C'
  when 60..69; 'D'
  when 0..59; 'F'
  else; 'Error'
  end
end

arraya = [100,90,100,99,99]
puts get_grade(arraya)
#=> A
```